# Class and ID auto completion problem in VS Code

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, autocomplete

When I want to use a class or an ID that i have previously written in my html file, the auto completion does not work. It does not either work in the same html file or in css or js files. Actually `ctrl + space` works in the same html file *just for some classes, but not all of them*, and also it is hard to always hit `ctrl + space` specially when it is not supposed to work always.

Here are the things I have tried:

- Updating VS Code
- Disabling all auto completion extensions
- Enabling different extensions one by one

I have searched so much and used different extensions, but none of them worked. Is there any solution somebody knows?

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem, I solved this using below extension:

[Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solnurkarim.html-to-css-autocompletion)

Also check bottom right of vs code..
[image: this should be html]

this should be html while writing html

Happy Coding!